# Azure AD B2B all users get created in Primary Directory

Tags: azure, entra-domain-services

I am creating an app that will live on Azure.  I am attempting to use the Azure AD security to restrict access to the application.  On top of that I want this to be an invitation only application, not something you find in the app store.  Enter the lovely B2B implementation, which is just a snazzy word for a CSV upload utility.

I had hoped to be able to create custom directories and then add the users specific to that directory like Company ABC.  However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this through the Azure site.  The only user that can use the B2B upload utility has to be created as a "Global Admin" and also at least a Co-Administrator. I keep thinking that there has to be an easier way to use an invitation process to manage who has access to this application.

Comment: One limitation not mentioned in that link in @Pascal's answer is something I describe here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36205241/need-help-setting-up-b2b-authentication-in-azure-ad#comment60058829_36205241 Does that describe the major issue for you?

Answer (score 0):

There are some limitations during the preview, one of which being the necessity to be an AAD global admin to upload the CSV.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2b-current-preview-limitations/